# What does y(x) do in this arrow funtion

Tags: javascript

I do not get what  y(x) in the third line does

```js
var x = 5;

var y = 1;

( (x, y)=>(y => y(x) + 1)(x => x * 3 + y) ) (x, y);

// returns 17
```

I suspect that the f(x) calls the arrow function on the right.

Comment: First and foremost you should not reuse the variable names `x` and `y` because it can be confusing having different variables with the same name. Javascript can understand it perfectly however our human brains find it hard to read. So I'd rewrite the function as `((a,b)=>(c=>c(a)+1)(d=>d*3+b))(x,y)`. This is exactly the same function but more human readable because we're not reusing the names `x` and `y` for everything

Comment: If this is anything other than a learning exercise, I recommend telling whoever wrote this to reevaluate their code style.

Comment: And further to slebetman's comment: Give variables *meaningful names*

Comment: it's a question about scopes and closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That:

```
(y => y(x) + 1)
```

is a lambda (an anonymous function) that takes a function `y` as an argument.

Its argument is:

```
(x => x * 3 + y)
```

Thus it is the same as:

```
((x => x * 3 + y)(x) + 1)
((x*3)+y)+1
```

and all this is part of a function (`(x, y)=> …`) which is applied with the arguments (5,1).